# How to generate a 2hour-long blank video

Tags: shell, opencv, video

I'd like to generate a video with a black or white background (or even nothing at all) that lasts for a specific duration (e.g. 2 hour long).

Can you please suggest a fast way to do it programatically (e.g. command line, OpenCV)? Thanks.

Comment: You can use a program such as Paint to produce a black or white image, and then display that image on your screen for any length of time.

Comment: I am not too sure this is programming related at all...

Comment: Yeah even though I put OpenCV as a hint, I was not clear about the programming in my original question. I updated the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You can use **ffmpeg** for this:

```
ffmpeg -t 7200 -s 640x480 -f rawvideo -pix_fmt rgb24 -r 25 -i /dev/zero empty.mpeg
```

**UPDATE**:

```
-t:       length of the video (in H:m:s format 00:00:00 or in seconds 0.000)
-s:       frame size
-f:       video format
-pix_fmt: pixel format
-r:       fps
-i:       input
```

Comment: Would you please explain all those switches? I beg, Sy Borg.

Comment: Shouldn't `-r 1` suffice? And do you know what exactly is a rawvideo?

Comment: On my system, `-r 1` produces this error: "MPEG1/2 does not support 5/1 fps"

Comment: You can leave `-r 1` if fps is not important. `rawvideo` says, that video will be uncompressed.

Comment: FYI, `ffmpeg -t 7200 -s qcif -f rawvideo -pix_fmt rgb24 -r 1/3600 -i /dev/zero -r 24 /tmp/silence.mpeg` made the conversion process go faster.

Comment: When i set `-t`, for ex., to 120, VLC shows it's 1:46 time left, but plays 2:00. QuickTime Player calculates movie length correctly. `ffmpeg` log says `time=00:01:59.96`. I think it's just player time approximation problem.

Comment: I've found that if you are using `avconv` then you need to put the `-t` option after your input file.

Comment: What do we do on Windows, where `/dev/zero` does not exist?

Comment: & how to add blank audio as well?

Comment: "What do we do on Windows, where /dev/zero does not exist?" ---> set -i to an image file such as C:\user\Pictures\picture.png

Comment: It doesn't create me a file at all... . What should i do?

Answer (score 52):

For an h264 output in a MP4 container, use:

```
ffmpeg -t 7200 -f lavfi -i color=c=black:s=640x480 -c:v libx264 -tune stillimage -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4
```

If you want to include an audio track, simply add the arguments for the audio input and encoding (if necessary). The output's duration will be determined by the shortest input, i.e. the audio. For example:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=c=black:s=640x480 -i audio.ogg -c:v libx264 -tune stillimage -pix_fmt yuv420p -shortest -c:a aac -b:a 128k output-with-audio.mp4
```

Comment: if it's needed to generate single IDR frame with black color use '-vframes 1' :            ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=c=black:s=1920x1088 -c:v libx264 -tune stillimage -pix_fmt yuv420p -vframes 1 -y black.h264

Comment: This is a better one.