# FFmpeg not creating video file (empty.mpeg) - No output or error messages

Tags: c#, video, ffmpeg

I am using FFmpeg in C# to create a blank video file with the following command:

```
string ffmpegPath = "path/to/ffmpeg";
string outputPath = "empty.mpeg";

string command = $"{ffmpegPath} -t 7200 -s 640x480 -f rawvideo -pix_fmt rgb24 -r 25 -i /dev/zero {outputPath}";

// ... code to execute FFmpeg command ...
```

However, when running the code, the empty.mpeg file is not created, and no output or error messages are printed to the console. I have verified that FFmpeg is properly installed on my system, and the paths to the executable and output file are correct.

I tried redirecting the standard error stream and handling the error messages, but still no errors are being displayed. I also attempted different file formats and extensions, but the issue persists.

I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions to resolve this issue. Thank you!

Link to my related question on Stack Overflow (for reference): [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11453082/how-to-generate-a-2hour-long-blank-video)

Comment: The question you linked was deleted

Comment: Why is that????

Comment: Post to meta and ask them why